# Event handling in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Taking Jeff Atwood's [advice](https://blog.codinghorror.com/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninjas/), I decided to use a JavaScript library for the very basic to-do list application I'm writing. I picked the [Dojo toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/), version 1.1.1. At first, all was fine: the drag-and-drop code I wrote worked first time, you can drag tasks on-screen to change their order of precedence, and each drag-and-drop operation calls an event handler that sends an AJAX call to the server to let it know that order has been changed.

Then I went to add in the email tracking functionality. Standard stuff: new incoming emails have a unique ID number attached to their subject line, all subsequent emails about that problem can be tracked by simply leaving that ID number in the subject when you reply. So, we have a list of open tasks, each with their own ID number, and each of those tasks has a time-ordered list of associated emails. I wanted the text of those emails to be available to the user as they were looking at their list of tasks, so I made each task box a Dijit "Tree" control - top level contains the task description, branches contain email dates, and a single "leaf" off of each of those branches contains the email text.

First problem: I wanted the tree view to be fully-collapsed by default. After searching Google quite extensively, I found a number of solutions, all of which seemed to be valid for previous versions of Dojo but not the one I was using. I eventually figured out that the best solution would seem to be to have a event handler called when the Tree control had loaded that simply collapsed each branch/leaf. Unfortunately, even though the Tree control had been instantiated and its "startup" event handler called, the branches and leaves still hadn't loaded (the data was still being loaded via an AJAX call). So, I modified the system so that all email text and Tree structure is added server-side. This means the whole fully-populated Tree control is available when its startup event handler is called.

So, the startup event handler fully collapses the tree. Next, I couldn't find a "proper" way to have nice formatted text for the email leaves. I can put the email text in the leaf just fine, but any HTML gets escaped out and shows up in the web page. Cue more rummaging around Dojo's documentation (tends to be out of date, with code and examples for pre-1.0 versions) and Google. I eventually came up with the solution of getting JavaScript to go and read the SPAN element that's inside each leaf node and un-escape the escaped HTML code in it's innerHTML. I figured I'd put code to do this in with the fully-collapse-the-tree code, in the Tree control's startup event handler.

However... it turns out that the SPAN element isn't actually created until the user clicks on the expando (the little "+" symbol in a tree view you click to expand a node). Okay, fair enough - I'll add the re-formatting code to the onExpand() event handler, or whatever it's called. Which doesn't seem to exist. I've searched to documentation, I've searched Google... I'm quite possibly mis-understanding Dojo's "publish/subscribe" event handling system, but I think that mainly because there doesn't seem to be any comprehensive documentation for it anywhere (like, where do I find out what events I can subscribe to?).

So, in the end, the best solution I can come up with is to add an onClick event handler (not a "Dojo" event, but a plain JavaScript event that Dojo knows nothing about) to the expando node of each Tree branch that re-formats the HTML inside the SPAN element of each leaf. Except... when that is called, the SPAN element still doesn't exist (sometimes - other times it's been cached, just to further confuse you). Therefore, I have the event handler set up a timer that periodically calls a function that checks to see if the relevant SPAN element has turned up yet before then re-formatting it.

```
// An event handler called whenever a "email title" tree node is expanded.
function formatTreeNode(nodeID) {
    if (dijit.byId(nodeID).getChildren().length != 0) {
        clearInterval(nodeUpdateIntervalID);
        messageBody = dijit.byId(nodeID).getChildren()[0].labelNode.innerHTML
        if (messageBody.indexOf("<b>Message text:</b>") == -1) {
            messageBody = messageBody.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
            messageBody = messageBody.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
            messageBody = messageBody.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
            dijit.byId(nodeID).getChildren()[0].labelNode.innerHTML = "<b>Message text:</b><div style=\"font-family:courier\">"+messageBody+"</div>";
        }
    }
}

// An event handler called when a tree node has been set up - we changed the default fully-expanded to fully-collapsed.
function setupTree(theTree) {
    dijit.byId("tree-"+theTree).rootNode.collapse();

    messageNode = dijit.byId("tree-"+theTree).rootNode.getChildren();
    for (pl = 0; pl < messageNode.length; pl++) {
        messageNode[pl].collapse();
        messageNode[pl].expandoNode.onclick = eval("nodeUpdateIntervalID = setInterval(\"formatTreeNode('"+messageNode[pl].id+"')\",200); formatTreeNode('"+messageNode[pl].id+"');");
    }
}
```

The above has the feel of a truly horrible hack, and I feel sure I must have taken a wrong turn somewhere early on in my thought process. Can someone please tell me:

- The correct way to go about putting nicely-formatted text inside a Dojo/Dijit Tree control.
- The correct way to handle Dojo events, like where I can figure out what events are available for me to subscribe to.
- A better JavaScript library to use (can I do what I want to with JQuery and avoid the all-around-the-houses approach seen above?).

PS: If you're naming a software project, give thought to its name's uniqueness in Google - I'm sure searching for "Dojo" documentation in Google would be easier without all the martial arts results getting in the way.

PPS: Firefox spellchecker knows how to spell "Atwood", correcting me when I put two 'T's instead of one. Is Jeff just that famous now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you followed the [dijit.Tree and dojo.data in Dojo 1.1](http://dojotoolkit.org/2008/02/12/dijit-tree-and-dojo-data-dojo-1-1) tutorial which directed you to pass the data to the tree control using a data store. That had me banging my head of a brick wall for a while.

Its not really a great approach and the alternative is not really well documented. You need to create a use model instead. I have included an example below of a tree model that I created for displaying the structure of an LDAP directory.

You will find the default implementation of the model in your dojo distribution at ./dijit/_tree/model.js. The comments should help you understand the functions supported by the model.

The IDirectoryService class the code below are stubs for server-side Java POJOs generated by [Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org) (DWR). I highly recommend DWR if you going to be doing a lot of client-server interaction.

```
dojo.declare("LDAPDirectoryTreeModel", [ dijit.tree.model ], {
    getRoot : function(onItem) {
        IDirectoryService.getRoots( function(roots) {
            onItem(roots[0])
        });
    },

    mayHaveChildren : function(item) {
        return true;
    },

    getChildren : function(parentItem, onComplete) {
        IDirectoryService.getChildrenImpl(parentItem, onComplete);
    },

    getIdentity : function(item) {
        return item.dn;
    },

    getLabel : function(item) {
        return item.rdn;
    }
});
```

And here is an extract from the my JSP page where I created the model and used it to populate the tree control.

```
<div
  dojoType="LDAPDirectoryTreeModel"
  jsid="treeModel"
  id="treeModel">
</div>
<div
  jsid="tree"
  id="tree"
  dojoType="dijit.Tree" model="treeModel"
  labelAttr="name"
  label="${directory.host}:${directory.port}">
</div>
```